# Is it possible to do integer math with nodes without casting to float?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, mathematics, conversion

Question is as the title says. Specifically, I was wondering if there is an integer variant for the Modulo Math node (and by extension all math nodes, I imagine integer division would be useful, for example).

Here is my use case: I have this setup where I want to select every other vertex, and I'm doing so by checking to see if the index is odd.

Below is what I imagine `index % 2 == 0` translates to in node-format.

[image]

But, the Modulo (Math) node does not have a type setting like the Equals (Compare) node does, it only works with floats, so in the image you see everything gets converted to float temporarily before it goes back to integer again for the comparison. As a programmer myself, it seems weird that I'm casting to float halfway through an operation that really has nothing to do with floating point values.

I also know that at higher values floats start to become imprecise, and so I imagine this check won't accurately be able to tell if an index is odd for objects with many vertices. I'm well aware that floats can store integers up to 16.7 million ([source](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/11/21/floating-point-precision/)) before that starts happening, but still.

Comment: See https://developer.blender.org/D13764

Comment: @scurest I take it that means this is not currently possible? That diff looks very promising though.